# Show Navigation Bar At The End of A TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The navigation bar is not displayed at the end of the tableview. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if([indexPath row] == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection: 0] - 1){
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO
                                                 animated:YES];
        DDLogVerbose(@"Reached end of tableview");
    }

}
```

The "Reached end of tableview" is outputted to Xcode, but the navigation bar (previously hidden), does not re-appear.

I have also tried using `willDisplayCell` but that shows the navigation bar too early, just before the last cell is on screen, this is not ideal.

**Why does the navigation bar not re-appear at the end of the tableview, even though the if statement is entered? What should I do to make it re-appear?**

---

Update: Great answers everyone, although I'd also appreciate if someone could possibly explain to me, why the above code does not work. Thanks!

Comment: At my end didEndDisplayingCell is not calling because I have 6.0

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` is a `UIScrollView`, so you can use its `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method to decide, based on its `contentOffset` vs. `contentSize`, to show or hide just about anything.

Comment: Awesome answer, I will wait to see if anyone knows why my above code does not work, but if know one knows what might be wrong with my code, you'll get the checkmark @Cyrille

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not the best solution, but you could try adding another row (dummy row at the end), then when willDisplayCell for that row gets called, you should the navigation bar, hiding the dummy row.

Answer (score 0):

In view didLoad set navigation bar hidden

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

And then check this method works or not

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row){
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    float offs = (scrollView.contentOffset.y+scrollView.bounds.size.height);
    float val = (scrollView.contentSize.height);

    if (offs==val)
    {

   // Code

    }


}
```

May this help you .